# MySQL- Mysql-server uninstall ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I want to remove mysql with all data and reinstall it back. After uninstall and new installation all users are the same. Can i remove it and wipe all users, to have only one new root user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
apt-get --purge remove "mysql*"
```

This helped me.